# How to group values with unique incremental keys in Kotlin?

Tags: collections, kotlin

For example, I have such list:

```
{{1,"a"},{2,"a"},{3,"b"},{4,"b"},{5,"b"},{6,"a"},{7,"a"},{8,"a"}}
```

If I use Kotlin's`groupBy { it.value }` then it'll be like this:

```
{
   a: = {1,2,6,7,8},
   b: = {3,4,5}
}
```

But I want to group it like this:

```
{
   a1: = {1,2},
   b1: = {3,4,5},
   a2: = {6,7,8}
}
```

What Kotlin's function should I use?

Comment: Why is `6` in `a2` and not in `a1` ? What decides the key in your expected map?

Comment: @GuiSim My list has sublists of elements with same values. Each sublist should be grouped with custom key (string value + incremental id). In other words, if I have next group of elements with already added key `a`, it should be considered as new key (`a2`, or whatever)

Comment: You will probably have to make your own implementation for this; it won't be available out of what's built-in.

Comment: @Lester could we help you (see answers) :)?

Comment: Yep, thanks, I 'm accepting your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `List` (since order matters) of `Pair<Int, String>` like this:

```
val list = listOf(1 to "a", 2 to "a", 3 to "b", 4 to "b", 5 to "b", 6 to "a", 7 to "a", 8 to "a")
```

you can do something like this:

```
fun groupCount(list: List<Pair<Int, String>>): Map<String, List<Int>> {
    val countMap = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    var currentStr = list.firstOrNull()?.second ?: return emptyMap()

    return list.map { (key, value) ->

        if(currentStr != value) {
            currentStr = value
            countMap[value] = ((countMap[value] ?: 0) + 1)
        }

        key to value + countMap.getOrPut(value, {1})
    }.groupBy ({it.second}, {it.first})
}
```

In the end Kotlin's [groupBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html#groupby) becomes especially handy when you need to turn this

> [(1, a1), (2, a1), (3, b1), (4, b1), (5, b1), (6, a2), (7, a2), (8, a2)]

into this:

> {a1=[1, 2], b1=[3, 4, 5], a2=[6, 7, 8]}

---

If you happen to have a `Map<Int, String>` you can call `toList()` before you pass it to `groupCount`.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a pretty special use case I guess. One, not quite functional, implementation could look like this:

```
fun subgroups(data: Map<Int, String>): Map<String, List<Int>> {
    if (data.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException()
    val counter = data.values.toSet().associateWithTo(mutableMapOf()){ 1 }
    var last = data.values.first()
    val result = mutableMapOf<String, List<Int>>()
    data.forEach { k, v ->
        if (v != last) {
            counter[last] = counter.getOrDefault(last, 0) + 1
            last = v
        }

        "$v${counter[v]}".let { key ->
            result[key] = result.getOrDefault(key, listOf()) + k
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = input
  .fold(
    mutableListOf<Pair<String, MutableList<Int>>>() to mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
  ) { acc, pair ->
    val result = acc.first
    val counters = acc.second
    val number = pair.first
    val letter = pair.second
    if (result.lastOrNull()?.first == letter + counters[letter]) {
      result.last().second.add(number)
    } else {
      result.add(letter + (counters.getOrElse(letter) { 0 } + 1).also { counters[letter] = it } to mutableListOf(number))
    }
    acc
  }
  .first
  .toMap()
```